# how a galvanic cell works with a different metal cation in electrolyte than used in electrode

Tags: electrochemistry

A traditional galvanic uses zinc as the anode electrode submerged in a zinc sulfate electrolyte, and copper as the cathode electrode submerged in a a copper sulfate electrolyte. I wanted to know what happens if the electrolyte metal cation was not zinc or copper: What if the anode electrolyte was Potassium sulfate and the cathode electrolyte was sodium sulfate, will the cell still operate?

Should't zinc still be oxidized to zinc ion? In the cathode half cell, would the sodium ions be reduced to sodium metal, or would copper electrode interfere in some way?